# Second Flyway migration script does not recognize changes from first migration script

Tags: postgresql, quarkus, flyway

I'm using flyway migration scripts inside a quarkus application with a database dev services.

Firstly the issue:
I created 2 tables  with the first migration script (V1.0.0__create_inital_tables.sql)
as seen in the screen below
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zhEIJ.png)

In my second script (V2.0.0__insert_admin_user.sql) i want to insert data into these tables.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gpvxW.png)

The issue is that the tables are created but the data is not inserted. Clearly the Intellij IDE gives me some indication here already that the TB_USER and the TB_USER_ROLES are not recognized yet in the second script.

I can solve this issue with a "fix" if i commit the db changes of the first script and insert the values within the first script. But i would like to be able to use multiple migration scripts.

For completeness here is the relevant content of my application.properties:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jaksl.png)

Thank you very much for your time and effort.

What did i try:

I tried changing the naming of the migration scripts.
As mentioned, commiting the first script "solved" the issue but not completly.
Ive also tried various IDE recommendations, but they just try to connect to the db, which i cant as the dev services spin up the DB on demand only.

Comment: Enable DEBUG and post the logs, you can try also renaming scripts to lowercase version `v1.0.0__name.sql`
`quarkus.log.level=DEBUG
quarkus.log.category."org.flywaydb".level=DEBUG
`
Also you can use import.sql in resources for initial import of data.